# Is it possible to use GeoSparql with GeoJSON objects on AWS Neptune?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

The documentation for AWS Neptune does not indicate that it supports the GeoSPARQL extension. Is there any way to support geospatial queries that we have stored as GeoJSON objects? Perhaps using Gremlin? We are considering Azure Cosmos as an alternative but would rsther stay in the AWS ecosphere. Thank you!

Added re: comment for GeoJSON specifics:

As a recent workaround, we have been exploring the use of Geohashing and bounding boxes to solve this in a NoSQL store . Or, the original Azure Cosmos direction. The problem with the former solution is the computational time to do so at scale, and then fetch and combine results from the graph with some type of unique ID mapping. Instead, traversing raw lat/long coordinates via GeoJSON enabled queries in the graph  means that we could do everything in one pass. Ultimately it enables dramatically simpler architecture and cleaner DEVOPS.

In regards to specifics, mostly just querying items within a radius or manhattan distance of a given point. We don't currently use polygons but have been considering it for various use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on the types of geospatial queries that you'd want to support over the GeoJSON objects?

Comment: Absolutely! Added to the original question. Thanks Brad.

Answer (score 0):

From the latest [AWS Neptune User Guide (PDF)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/neptune-ug.pdf) in the section on Blazegraph to Neptune compatibility (dated Dec 2020 at time of writing):

> **Geospatial search** – Blazegraph supports the configuration of namespaces that enable geospatial
> support. This feature is not yet available in Neptune.

Therefore, the answer appears to be 'no' if using out-the-box functionality.